# What libraries should I use for a Linux desktop panel?

Tags: gtk, x11, gnome, cairo, gtk3

I'm thinking about making a panel for Linux, that would include window list, menu, clock etc. My 2 requirenments are:

- It should fit into MATE (Gnome 2 fork) and possibly Gnome 3 2D mode.
- It should have smooth animations (for drag & drop window button reordering like tabs in Chrome).

What libraries should I use? GTK+ / Cairo / Clutter / something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can start checking `libgnome-panel` (probably renamed to `libmate-panel`).  The gnome-panel is built on top of that and `libgnome-panel` provides what is necessary to build applets (like the window list, etc.).

Each applet has its own dependencies, for instance, for window lists you will need `libwcnk`, for clock you might need `cairo`.  For a panel with smooth animations, you might need clutter (that is OpenGL), however, that might not fit with the 2D you are looking for.